# Limit is ignored in python boto aws simpleDB queries

Tags: python, amazon-simpledb, boto

The following query returns all the records instead of just 2. When I run the query in the AWS SimpleDB browser it works, however. Am I using boto wrong?

```
conn = boto.connect_sdb()
dom = conn.get_domain('taxplan')
query = 'select Descr, PlanName, ItemName, Plan, ReceivedTime from taxplan limit 2'
rs = dom.select(query)
sl= []
for j in rs:
    sl.append(j)
result['sboto'] = convert(sl[1:])

sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result,indent=1))
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems the problem is the:

```
for j in rs:
```

It seems that the query is being run multiple times, because of the iteration, not sure exactly.  I fixed the problem for me by replacing:

```
rs = dom.select(query)
```

with

```
rs = dom.select(query,max_items=2)
```

Hope that helps.